# Create dict from register var

Tags: ansible

I am having trouble trying to format a script output with lines like:

```
"key1:val1"
```

Register it in a var which gives :

```
"var.stdout_lines": [ "key1:val1", ]

And I would like to set_fact from this var to a dictionary like :
- name: 'set dict fact'
  set_fact:
    dict: "{{dict|combine(var.stdout_lines)}}"
```

I've an exit like :

```
combine expects dictionaries, got Undefined"
```

Is someone knows how to format correctly my script output to properly be combine by my dict ?

THKS

Answer (score 1):

Multiple problems here:

1. `dict` is not initialized, so it's `Undefined` and when you try to combine it with something, it doesn't work. A first step would be to use a `default` filter:

   ```
   dict: "{{ dict| default({}) | combine(var.stdout_lines) }}"
   ```
2. [`combine` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) is for combining dictionaries, but `var.stdout_lines` is a list, not a dict, so you would get another error : "|combine expects dictionaries, got [u'key1:val1']"

A solution I see is to transform your lines into a string representation of a dict, then use the [`from_json` filter](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data):

```
- set_fact:
    dict: "{{ ('{' + (var.stdout_lines | map('regex_replace', '(.*):(.*)', '\"\\1\":\"\\2\"') | join(',')) + '}') | from_json }}"
```

Be careful: it doesn't handle the case when keys or values contains double-quote char `"`.